# DataGridView CellFormatting event firing repeatedly while trying to link ComboBox column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell, cell-formatting

I have a `DataGridView` populated by a `DataTable`. The view is in a form which is to be used to allow a user to edit the data, add new rows etc. One of the columns in the set, I want to be selectable from a list via a `ComboBox`. Because there is pre-existing data loaded at the start (the "current state"), I have to add a separate `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` and then "set" the values for the pre-existing data from an identifier in a separate (hidden) column. I set the `DisplayType` of the combobox column to `Nothing` so that they appear like flat textboxes.

```
Private featureIDColumn As DataGridViewColumn
Private cboFeatureColumn As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

With dgv
    .DataSource = dtbMyDataTable
    featureIDColumn = .Columns("FeatureID")
    featureIDColumn.Visible = False
    cboFeatureColumn = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn() With {.DisplayIndex = featureIDColumn.Index + 1}
    With cboFeatureColumn
        .Name = "Feature"
        .DataSource = dtbFeatureList    ' Simple two-column lookup of ID's and values
        .ValueMember = "ID"
        .DisplayMember = "FriendlyName"
        .HeaderText = "Feature"
        .DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing
    End With
    .Columns.Add(cboFeatureColumn)
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
        Dim cboCell As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = CType(row.Cells(cboFeatureColumn.Index), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
        cboCell.Value = row.Cells(featureIDColumn.Index).Value
    Next
End With
```

I've added a (derived) button column to the grid with the intention that when the user clicks it, a new record is inserted and the `DisplayType` of the `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` *on that specific row* changes to `ComboBox` (so they can select the value from the dropdown) but all the other cells in the column retain the appearance of a flat textbox.

```
Private Sub copyAction(clickedCell As DataGridViewCustomButtonCell)
    Try
        Dim activeRow As DataGridViewRow = dgv.Rows(clickedCell.RowIndex)
        Dim newRow As DataRow = dtbMyDataTable.NewRow
        For Each dtc As DataColumn In dtbMyDataTable.Columns
            Select Case dtc.ColumnName
                Case "FeatureID"
                    newRow.Item(dtc.ColumnName) = 0
                Case "Status"
                    newRow.Item(dtc.ColumnName) = "New"
                Case Else
                    ' Various default values are set for certain columns
            End Select
        Next
        dtbActive.Rows.Add(newRow)
        dtbActive.AcceptChanges()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub dgv_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellFormatting
    Try
        If Not e.RowIndex < 0 Then
            Dim activeRow As DataGridViewRow = dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex)
            For Each cll As DataGridViewCell In activeRow.Cells
                If activeRow.Cells(statusColumn.Index).Value = "New" Then
                    If cll.ColumnIndex = cboFeatureColumn.Index Then
                        Dim cbo As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = CType(dgv.Rows(cll.RowIndex).Cells(cll.ColumnIndex), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
                        cbo.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox
                        cll.Style.BackColor = Color.White
                        cll.Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkBlue
                        cll.ReadOnly = False
                    Else
                        cll.Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
                        cll.Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen
                        cll.ReadOnly = True
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

When they select an item from the dropdown, the associated value (identifier) is updated in the ID field (this is the "true" record; the `ComboBox` is merely there to serve as an easy means of selecting from a specific set of values)

```
Private Sub dgv_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellValueChanged
    Try
        Dim changedCell As DataGridViewCell = CType(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex), DataGridViewCell)
        If changedCell.ColumnIndex = cboFeatureColumn.Index Then
            Dim changedCombo = CType(changedCell, DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
            dgv.Rows(changedCell.RowIndex).Cells(featureIDColumn.Index).Value = changedCombo.Value
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

But - as soon as the new record is created, all the values in the combobox column for the pre-existing records, disappear? And that, I am assuming, is because the combobox column only exists in the `DataGridView`, not in the underlying `DataTable` (?) So the `DataGridView` refreshes from its `DataSource` and blanks that column.

Okay - so to get around that problem, I created a `Sub` that refreshes that column from the ID column which I can call whenever the data changes :

```
Private Sub RefreshFeatureColumn()
    Try
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
            Dim cboCell As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = CType(row.Cells(cboFeatureColumn.Index), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
            cboCell.Value = row.Cells(featureIDColumn.Index).Value
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

But now, whenever I click the button, it appears to me that the `CellFormatting` (and/or possibly the `CellPainting` ?) event is just firing constantly, rendering the form unusable (it's just flickering perpetually and not capturing any clicks - effectively, hanging)

So - I'm obviously doing something badly wrong, but how else can I use a `ComboBox` column to manipulate the value in the ID column? Is there any way of handling the `CellFormatting` events such that it only fires when I want/need it to? Or, perhaps more appropriately, is there a way I can achieve what I'm trying to achieve in a way that doesn't fire the `CellFormatting` event perpetually like this?

Thanks in advance and apologies for the length of the question, I stripped the code down as much as I possibly could but wanted to include as much as possible to fully explain what it is I'm trying to do (and I can't imagine I'm the first?) I'm sure there's a far more elegant way of doing this but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need cellformatting event you can do your code on the mouse click or mouse double click event on your datagridview
all you have to do is to remove the event from the cellformatting event against your datagrid and create an event on mouse click or mouse double click and try to write your code from there

try that and let me what happened

Comment: There are some other events that you can do that are datagridview cell click or datagridview cell content click.they both fired up against mouse click but the minor difference is that datagridview cell click fires when you click anywhere in that cell but the datagridview cell content click only fired when you click the text on that cell if it is a text field unlike a button in a datagridview

Comment: there is another way that is you can hide and unhide the columns on the combobox value

Comment: okay thanks @ammad let me tinker with the code and see what happens, there's a lot more going on than what I posted so may take me a while to modify everything to suit!

Comment: that worked! i basically reduced the CellFormatting handler to just look after basic cell styles and stripped out everything else. Any manipulation of the cells is done via the handler for the buttons and only modifies the content on the current row. Looking just the way I want it now, thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome my friend